Sort values and remove "0" with formula
Im trying to sort values using a formula..
I started with great confidence but ended up with a headache :)
If A1 = 0, i want the value from the next cell on the same row, less or greater than 0 to show up, and so on. Row by row.
Excluding all 0 values and sorting the values less or greater than 0 from first cell on the left.
Is this even possible by only using formulas?
I have tried different solutions with IF, INDEX, SORT, FILTER .. but im getting nowhere close to what im trying to do.
First image showing the start values:

And this is what im trying to accomplish using only formulas:

Thankful for all help I can get!
Best regards
Jack

Here is one way to accomplish the desired output using one single dynamic array formula:


• Formula used in cell F1
=LET(
     a, A1:D4, 
     IFNA(DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y, 
     VSTACK(x,SORT(TOROW(INDEX(a,y,)/(INDEX(a,y,)<>0),2))))),1),""))


• Or, If you want to fill down for each row then:
=LET(a, A1:D1, SORT(TOROW(a/(a<>0),2)))


• Or with using FILTER() function:
=LET(a, A1:D1, SORT(FILTER(a,a<>0,"")))


Or, this way as well:
=LET(
     a, A1:D4,
     b, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
     IFNA(DROP(REDUCE(0,b,LAMBDA(x,y,
     LET(z, INDEX(a,y,), VSTACK(x,
     SORT(FILTER(z,z<>0)))))),1),""))



Logically not but LET brings nothing. Also, SORT is not expected.

Yes, it does avoids the repeat usage of ranges. so i did. SORT() used to get a sorted a range. Its an added bonus.


Among the formulas in the answer, the formula #3 only passes the test with all 0 in a row. 2) As I already noted, SORT function is not necessary as per request (the illustration). Fortunately, it doesn't affect calculations since it sorts by rows.


Move Undesired Values to the Right
=LET(data,A2:D6,crit,0,rep,"",
    d,IF(data=crit,rep,data),
    rc,ROWS(d),
    cc,COLUMNS(d),
    rs,SEQUENCE(rc),
    s,SEQUENCE(rc,cc)+(rs-1)*cc,
    ss,s+(d=rep)*cc,
    r,WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(d),TOCOL(ss)),cc),
    r)


Replace the bottom most r with any of the other variables to see what they hold.


Edit

Credits to rotabor for pointing out that the -1 is redundant. I'm only changing it in the following formulas since it was used in an effort to start the ˙s˙ sequence with 1 as illustrated in the screenshot.
I could have used +100 instead, and the formula would still work because it is only necessary that each row in the s sequence has consecutive ascending values and the difference between each next row is 8 (twice the number of columns).
The extra 4 (column) numbers are used to index the undesired values by using an IF formula that will add 4 to the s sequence for each 0 (the undesired value) producing the ss sequence.
The 'TOCOLed' data is then sorted by the 'TOCOLed' ss sequence and returned to its original shape using WRAPROWS.

Short

After removing the redundant variables and applying the proposed change (removing -1), you'll end up with the following formula:

=LET(data,A2:D6,crit,0,rep,"",
    d,IF(data=crit,rep,data),
    rc,ROWS(d),
    cc,COLUMNS(d),
    WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(d),TOCOL(SEQUENCE(rc,cc)
       +((d=rep)+SEQUENCE(rc))*cc)),cc))

IF/SEQUENCE

If you want to go down the IF/SEQUENCE road, you could use the following formula:

=LET(data,A2:D6,crit,0,rep,"",
    d,IF(data=crit,rep,data),
    rc,ROWS(d),
    cc,COLUMNS(d),
    rs,SEQUENCE(rc),
    s,IF(rs,SEQUENCE(,cc))+2*rs*cc,
    ss,s+(d=rep)*cc,
    r,WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(d),TOCOL(ss)),cc),
    r)


After removing the redundant variables, you'll end up with the following formula:

=LET(data,A2:D6,crit,0,rep,"",
    d,IF(data=crit,rep,data),
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),
    cc,COLUMNS(d),
    WRAPROWS(SORTBY(TOCOL(d),TOCOL(IF(rs,SEQUENCE(,cc))
        +(2*rs+(d=rep))*cc)),cc))

Efficiency

All formulas take about 2s to return the maximum number of rows.

Limitations

TOCOL has a limit of about 10^20 (1048576) values it can hold i.e. if there are 4 columns, it can deal with a maximum of 262145 rows. On the other hand, if there are 20 columns, the maximum is 52429 rows.
The following screenshot illustrates this behavior.



It's the original way.

In the final formula, -1 is extra.

I also want to contribute to solving this problem.
The gap of Excel is that a formula can't return the blank cell(s). Surely, the cell cannot be considered empty if it contains a formula. But in some case a blank cell can be in demand.
The DoSortByRows VBA subroutine is able resolving this demand.
Option Explicit

Sub DoSortByRows()
  Dim a, ac As Long, rc As Long, cc As Long
  ac = Selection.Areas.Count
  If ac <> 2 And ac <> 3 Then GoTo ErrorMsg
  a = SortByRows(Selection.Areas(1), Selection.Areas(2), Empty)
  If IsError(a) Then GoTo ErrorMsg
  rc = Selection.Areas(1).Rows.Count:  cc = Selection.Areas(1).Columns.Count
  If ac = 2 Then
    Selection.Areas(1) = a
  ElseIf ac = 3 Then
    Selection.Areas(3).Cells(1).Resize(rc, cc) = a
  End If
ExitSub:
  Exit Sub
ErrorMsg:
  MsgBox "Wrong arguments provided", , "DoSortByRows"
  GoTo ExitSub
End Sub

Function SortByRows(source As Variant, criteria As Variant, replacement As Variant) As Variant
  Dim src, crt, rc As Long, cc As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  If Not IsArray(source) Or Not IsArray(criteria) Or IsArray(replacement) Then
    SortByRows = CVErr(xlErrCalc)
    Exit Function
  End If
  src = source: crt = criteria: rc = UBound(src, 1): cc = UBound(src, 2)
  If rc <> UBound(crt, 1) Or cc <> UBound(crt, 2) Then
    SortByRows = CVErr(xlErrCalc)
    Exit Function
  End If
  For i = 1 To rc
    k = 1
    For j = 1 To cc
      If Not crt(i, j) Then
        src(i, k) = src(i, j)
        k = k + 1
      End If
    Next
    For j = k To cc
      src(i, j) = replacement
    Next
  Next
  SortByRows = src
End Function

DoSortByRows requires 2 or 3 ranges to be selected. The first range is the source table, the second range is the same size conditions array where unwanted values cause TRUE, and the optional third range is the new place for the result, otherwise the result overwrites the source.
The example with two selected ranges.
Select the first range then press and hold the Ctrl key and select the second range.

F11=A11:D14=0

Press Alt+F8 and run the DoSortByRows macro

A11:D14 can be purged at the end.
The example with three selected ranges.
Select the first range then press and hold the Ctrl key and select the second range then select the third range still holding Ctrl.


Finally, the SortByRows function is available to use on a worksheet:

F6=SortByRows(A6:D9,A6:D9=0,"")

